# Which I-94 date do I believe?

Tags: usa, b1-b2-visas, i-94

My I-94 permit was renewed early Jan, allowing entry through to July 5.  This showed both on the I-94 website and stamped in my passport.

I then traveled outside of the US for several months and returned in May, and I believed a new I-94 would have been issued on my arrival back into the US, and stamped in my passport it says Entry until November 11 (as expected).

[image]

However when I look it up on the I-94 website it still says the current I-94 is through to July 5.  I have checked my wife's passport, and all my kids - they are all stamped Nov 11, and on the I-94 it correctly says November 11, but online mine still has the date from the previous I-94.

[image]

Which date do I believe?  Am I going to need to do an early renew next time I enter?

**Note:** I will be entering by land, so it won't just be auto-renewed as it does when entering by air (which is what happened in May)

Comment: What country(s) did you travel to whilst you were away?

Comment: @Doc we traveled to New Zealand

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your passport has the correct date. Take it along to the nearest CBP Deferred Inspection site where they can correct the error.

The [CBP I-94 web site FAQ](https://i94.cbp.dhs.gov/I94/#/faq) says this:

> If there is an error or mistake on the paper or electronic form I-94,
>   the traveler can contact the Deferred Inspection office closest to
>   their location. A list of Deferred Inspection Sites and POEs can be
>   found on CBP's website, http://www.cbp.gov, under the "Ports" link at
>   the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the other answer is correct, and have marked it as the answer, however I am updating with details of what seems to have happened now.

We crossed 3 times in August without any issues.

First time there was no comment, just allowed to enter.  I checked I-94 website later, the new entry was there, but it still said Admit Until 05/07.

Second time the CBP officer asked if we needed to renew I-94 for all the passports (there were 6 of us), and I said "no, they should all be valid until 11/11", which I think he verified by looking at one or two of the stamps.  We were allowed to enter.  Checking I-94 website later again showed the latest entry, but still Admit until 05/07.

Third time the officer said nothing, didn't scan any of our passports, and let us in.  I-94 website still says 05/07, but this entry did not show at all.

I have so-far crossed once in September.  This time by foot (the entries above were by car).  Got the usual questions (where am I going, how long, where do I live, how long have I lived there), and was allowed to enter.  However this time the I-94 website shows the entry, and Admit Until 11/11.  So I'm guessing maybe the CBP officer at the pedestrian border crossing has updated the I-94 info based on the stamp in my passport.  He certainly didn't mention it.

[image]

So based on this experience it appears they're happy to update the electronic record based on what is stamped in the passport, but I certainly didn't actively request it or bring any attention to it, nor was it mentioned as a problem when I crossed.